Quiero saber que versión de c# tiene mi proyecto
Estoy realizando un upgrade de .Net y c# a una nueva versión, pero quisiera saber que versión de c# actualmente tiene el proyecto, tanto en mi local como en el IIS. Ya intenté ponerle ir a propiedades del proyecto pero no me sale la version del c#. Tambien puse en #error version y si me sale la version del lenguaje que es 7.3, pero quiero asegurarme de que la sintaxis del codigo este en esa version o si existira alguna otra alternativa, porseacaso tambien revise el archivo .csproj y no dice la version, es mi primera actualización que hare, ayuda.

Para conocer la versión del lenguaje que estamos utilizando en el proyecto, es útil estas dos opciones... la opcion 2 es las mas rapida ;)

OPCION 1 Ir a las propiedades del proyecto y en la solapa/pestana "Build" en en panel de vista avanzada tiene la version
OPCION 2 se puede incluir esta linea en el codigo "#error version" y arroja un error CS8304 con el mensaje que tiene la version del compilador y del lenguaje.

Para la OPCION 1

Para la OPCION 2
#error version


Esto genera un error, pero es util para verlo "rapidamente"

Sirve para cualquier version de .NET (ejemplo en proyecto webforms con NET FRamework) con la version de C# 7.3

Para modificar la version del lenguaje, hay que agregar la propiedad LangVersion

Si se quiere en un solo proyecto en el .csproj
Si se quieren todos los proyectos de una carpeta en el archivo Directory.Build.props

Mas info modificar la version del lenguaje
